# Averaging data from 2 input files in c++ stuck in a loop

Tags: c++, loops, fstream

I seem to stuck in an endless loop somewhere in my code but I cannot find where. I am doing an assignment for a class that asks me to average scores of 2 groups of students (the 2 input files) and output the results to results.out. I am getting stuck somewhere and need to know where I should look next. I have copied both my code and the two input files below. As of right now, I don't get anything in my results.out file.

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()    
{
    char courseID1;     //Course Letter
    char courseID2;
    int count = 1,
        sum = 0,
        sum2 = 0,
        k = 0,
        score;
    ifstream group1;    //Input stream for group1
    ifstream group2;    //Input stream for group2
    ofstream results;   //Output stream for the results

    //Open the input files
    group1.open("group1.dat");
    group2.open("group2.dat");

    //Open the output file
    results.open("results.out");

    while (count <= 5)
    {
        //Read the class ID
        group1 >> courseID1;
        group2 >> courseID2;
        sum = 0;
        k = 0;

        group1 >> score;
        while(score != -999)
        {
            k = k + 1;
            sum = sum + score;
        }

        float avg1 = (float)sum/k;
        k = 0;
        sum2 = 0;
        score = 0;
        group2 >> score;
        while (score != -999)
        {
            k = k + 1;
            sum = sum + score;
        }

        float avg2 = (float)sum2/k;

        results << "CourseID\tGroup No.\tCourse Average" << endl << endl;
        results << courseID1 << "\t1" << avg1;
        results << "\t\t2" << avg2 << endl << endl;

        count++;
    }

return 0;
} //end of main
```

group1.dat

```
A 80 100 50 10 32 90 89 100 23 50 -999
B 80 90 80 94 90 34 23 63 23 80 90 -999
C 10 30 20 10 90 50 89 23 90 68 90 10 60 90 73 35 90 -999
D 34 80 45 89 90 n23 90 12 34 90 84 100 90 59 -999
E 100 83 93 20 63 -999
```

group2.dat

```
A 20 75 40 25 80 89 100 60 -999
B 80 50 70 19 10 18 80 90 90 26 -999
C 100 30 20 40 90 50 18 90 90 45 90 80 70 30 35 40 -999
D 80 85 45 92 10 90 24 90 23 65 72 90 34 100 -999
E 95 100 88 98 69 -999
```

Here is what the output is supposed to look like:

```
courseID Group No. Course Average
    A          1        80.50
               2        82.75

    B          1        78.00
               2        75.35
```

EDIT:

I am now getting this result after changing the while loops to

```
while( (group >> score) && score != -999)
```

my result.out looks like this:

```
CourseID    Group No.   Course Average

A   162.4       20

CourseID    Group No.   Course Average

B   167.9091        20

CourseID    Group No.   Course Average

C   154.5882        20

CourseID    Group No.   Course Average

D   167.6       20

CourseID    Group No.   Course Average

D   1-NaN       20
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you try a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `group1 >> score` inside the loop before closing bracket. Something like this:

```
group1 >> score;
while(score != -999)
{
    k = k + 1;
    sum = sum + score;
    group1 >> score;
}
```

Same thing for the second loop

---

This looks better:

```
while( (group >> score) && score != -999 )
{
    k = k + 1;
    sum = sum + score;
}
```

Comment: I am now getting the result that looks like this:            CourseID Group No. Course Average

A 162.4  20

CourseID Group No. Course Average

B 167.9091  20

CourseID Group No. Course Average

C 154.5882  20

CourseID Group No. Course Average

D 167.6  20

CourseID Group No. Course Average

D 1-NaN  20

Comment: Not only does your second suggestion look better, it's actually correct.  The first suggestion (like everything in his code) uses the results of `>>` without checking whether it succeeds or not.  Which means that the slightest error in the input (e.g. a `'O'` instead of a `'0'`) will put the code into an endless loop as well.

Comment: Your comment saying that it is actually correct got me to figure this out. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your while statement:

```
while (score != -999){
    k = k + 1;
    sum = sum + score;
}
```

You are never modifying the value of 'score', thus creating an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (score != -999)
    {
        k = k + 1;
        sum = sum + score;
    }
```

You're stuck in this loop.  The loop only exits if `score == -999` and you don't modify the value of `score` anywhere in this loop.

Always use a debugger.  You'll pretty quickly find where your program gets stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, smth like this:

```
do
{
    group1 >> score;
    k = k + 1;
    sum = sum + score;
} while (score != -999);
```